How handling Concurrent Updates in ScyllaDB
I am using ScyllaDB and have a table called product with a column stock. When the stock changes, I perform a query to select the current stock, then calculate and update the new value in the database. However, when there are multiple concurrent requests, the calculations become incorrect.
Does ScyllaDB have a mechanism to handle this issue? I have tried using Lightweight Transactions (LWT), but it doesn't seem to be effective. The results of the select queries are always the same.
How can I ensure the accuracy of stock calculations with concurrent updates in ScyllaDB?
Thank you!

The LWT (LightWeight Transactions) feature definitely does work, so I'm not sure what you mean that it was not "effective", maybe you didn't use it correctly?
One approach of using LWT effectively is to use the optimistic locking technique:

To your item's data add a version column. Initialize new items (LWT IF NOT EXISTS) with version=0.
To modify the item, read the old value of the item including its version column, do whatever lengthy calculation you want to decide on the modified item, increment the version column in the item, and write the result back to the database with LWT IF version = <oldversion> (where oldversion is the version number you read from the old item, before the increment).
If the LWT write in step 2 succeeded, you're done. If it failed, it means you race with another update, and lost. So you need to start step 2 again (need to read the item again, calculate the modified item, and try again to write).

This approach is called "optimistic locking" because instead of preventing (via a lock) multiple threads from being in step 2 at the same time, each of them optimistically executes step 2 hoping it is the only one - and only when there is contention more work needs to be done. When the contention are possible but not very common, this is an efficient approach.
In some cases it it may be fine (depending on what exactly your are trying to calculate) to use the existing columns like your "stock" instead of adding a new version column. For example, you can read the existing value of "stock", calculate a new value, and then write with LWT IF stock = <oldstock> (where oldstock is the old value of stock). This approach is good, for example, when you want to safely increment a counter-like column.  But it may not work correctly for other calculations - if it's possible that some other thread's calculation will bring back the value to exactly the same value that your read despite having done other changes.
